# How to remove the file size limit in Symfony 2

Tags: file, symfony, file-upload, size

I'm working on a form in Symfony 2 and I got a problem with file upload. I tried changing the max size for something over 2M, but it always say that there's a 2M size limit. I will need to upload big files, like 53M. The best for my situation would be to have NO file size limit at all. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check these values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Comment: I guess that it means that I need to apply the same modification on my server?

Comment: yes file limit is a php thing not symfony